# iOS Application uses too much storage space

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults

Various users of our application started to complain it uses lots of memory on the phone. We added data collector based on files (that locates within application folder) and it's sizes, the following been found for small amount of users:

```
Preferences:{  
      files:{  
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist":"23.97479057312012",
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.0BTeiJo":"22.25380897521973",
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.1lT9kMO":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.2HHwLSb":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.2L9bkJR":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.2xAnoy5":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.3Qgyplk":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.4SBpAox":"23.95059013366699",
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.4Xm8NvI":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.5sPZPIi":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.6GOkP57":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.6SYZ1VF":"21.67253875732422",
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.6TJMV5r":"21.67211151123047",
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.6oNMJ0b":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.7C1Kuvm":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.7E3pmr4":0,
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.7ExLAx0":"21.70229721069336",
        "{bundle_identifier}.plist.7GOPE3W":"18.70771026611328",
        ...
      },
      size:"960.2354183197021"
```

Can someone assist and explain, why this files (plist.*) appeared and how it's possible to safely remove them and ensure they wont appear again?

P.S. I found the logic in the project where we store dictionaries to the NSUserDefaults (I know this is a bad practice), but there is not much data.

UPDATE:
I have discovered that files (`*.plist.*`) are generated after **Back Up**. And sometimes size is `0` sometimes size same as origin `*.plist` size (on back up time).
Now i need to know, is it safe to remove them?

Comment: Your application Memory is Leak due to this issue generate.

Comment: What's in the plists? Do you have data stored in them?

Comment: which folder have those `.plist` been created into?

Comment: this is default NSUserDefaults .plist file, located at ../Library/Preferences. other files have the same file name but with hash at the end.

Comment: Are you using NSUserDefaults to store the data, then it will keep on increasing when you add data to NSUserDefaults. You need some sort of arrays or dictionaries to store your data. NSUserDefaults will only be replenished when the application is deleted and installed again.